# A shortcut that assigns an icon to a running program window in KDE environment

Tags: icons, kde, plasma, icon-themes

Some programs have no icon and KDE assigns its default  icon [image] to them when they are running. Is there a way to create a shortcut to that program, so that the shortcut both runs the program and assigns an icon to that; so that the icon both appears in taskbar tabs and also the in program's titlebar?:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Or you could just change the default icon of the program you wish to run? This is how you do that:

You need to get a .png icon file that you would like to use and copy it to the following directory

```
~/.local/share/icons/hicolor/
```

This directory would contain a number of directories (they are named after the dimensions of the icon like 16x16 or 32x32)

You need to copy your .png icon file in the correct directory so if its 16x16 issue following command:

```
cp icon16x16.png ~/.local/share/icons/hicolor/16x16/apps
```

From there you would need do the following in a terminal:

```
sudo cp /usr/share/applications/application.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/
```

You need to change application.desktop to the application from which you want to change the icon (i.e. pidgin would become pidgin.desktop)

Then you need to edit the .desktop file:

```
nano ~/.local/share/applications/application.desktop
```

Look for the line that says:

```
Icon=application (i.e pidgin)
```

And change it to the new icon name without the .png prefix

```
Icon=icon16x16
```

Save changes, logout and log back in

Comment: Will it change the task manager icon for the running program? as in the image above?

Comment: Not sure but I think so.